# Puppet-Dashboard Doesn't Load With Ruby Gem Passenger 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, puppetmaster, rubygems, puppet-dashboard

Has anyone encountered problem of running Puppet Dashboard on Ruby Passenger 5? If yes does it really work with that Passenger version?

I've already setup and configured the necessary files required to run Puppet Dashboard via Passenger. Currently, the Apache test page is shown instead of the dashboard menu. This will not appear if Puppet-Dashboard is run in the lightweight Webrick server.

While scouring most of the installation samples and the manuals on how to install and configure it for Centos 6. I've seen most of them were based on Passenger 3 / 4. I am currently using 5.0.10 as it is used in conjunction with Puppet 3.8.1. One thing certain is that RailsAutoDetect is deprecated in version 5 and that has been commented out.

Below my puppet-dashboard.conf file (the load module has been moved to another file to avoid double-instantiation)

On the logs, the first error reported is that the path of /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/reports/upload is not there, so I've created those sub-folders to see if what would be the next error.

The next error in the log file after that is now shown like: Attempt to serve directory: /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/reports/upload/

External node and node terminus option has been commented out as not to disrupt normal puppet run-interval activities during office hours.

```
PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 6
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120 

Listen 3000
<VirtualHost *:3000>
   ServerName mi-cloud-mgmt-config-01
   ServerAlias mi-cloud-mgmt-config-01.mimos.local
   RailsBaseURI /
   PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/

# UPDATE THIS TO YOUR FQDN
<Directory /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/>
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/dashboard_error.log
LogLevel debug
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/dashboard_access.log combined
ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and noted that `/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/config.ru` didn't exist. I was able to correct the issue by doing

```
cp vendor/rails/railties/dispatches/config.ru .
```

while in `/usr/share/puppet-dashboard`.